# BackingStoreException occurs when 30,000 / 1 minute http request continues on jmeter for 5 minutes

Tags: exception, jmeter

During load verification using jmeter

jmeter script that issues 10,000 http requests per minute with jmeter
As shown below, it is executed 3 times * 10 times (minutes).

```
for i in 10
do
    jmeter -t 10000request.jmx >> jmeter.log &
    jmeter -t 10000request.jmx >> jmeter.log &
    jmeter -t 10000request.jmx >> jmeter.log &
    sleep 60
done
```

The following WARNING will occur frequently every 3 minutes.

java.util.prefs.FileSystemPreferences syncWorld WARNING: Couldn't flush user prefs: java.util.prefs.BackingStoreException: Couldn't get file lock.

I don't know the cause, I'm in trouble, and I can't apply the load as expected.

Could you tell me the cause and countermeasures?

Comment: Note: cross-posted to SOja https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/59284/19110

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [JMeter Bug 61279](https://bz.apache.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=61279) the issue is not connected with JMeter, it is between Java and your Linux file access rights. Make sure that the user you're running JMeter with has enough rights to access `/etc/.java/.systemPrefs/.system.lock` file.

Running JMeter under [root account](https://geek-university.com/linux/root-account/) should also help.

However I would recommend setting [systemRoot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/PreferencesFactory.html#systemRoot()) and [userRoot](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/prefs/PreferencesFactory.html#userRoot()) folders to the location where current user has read/write access to like:

```
./jmeter -Djava.util.prefs.systemRoot=/home/youruser/.jmeter -Djava.util.prefs.userRoot=/home/youruser/.jmeter/.userPrefs
```

To make the changes permanent you can add the above lines to *system.properties* file (lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation)

More information:

- [Apache JMeter Properties Customization Guide](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-properties-customization/)
- [Overriding Properties Via The Command Line](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#override)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I didn't make userRoot directory. I did Resolve this matter.